# How to check if Django Queryset returns more than one object?

Tags: python, html, django

Basically I have what I'm hoping is a simple issue, I just want to check if the Queryset contains more than one object but I'm not sure how to do it? What I've written (that doesn't work) is below.

```
{% if game.developer.all > 1 %} 
   <h1>Developers:</h1>
{% else %} 
   <h1>Developer:</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `QuerySet.count()`?

Comment: `queryset.exists()`

Comment: Where does that go because it doesn't work when I do game.developer.all.QuerySet.count()

Comment: @jec1918 try  `if game.developer.all.count()`instead

Comment: Yeah that didn't work... got this error message: "Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'game.developer.count()'"

Comment: Got rid of the brackets and it works thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `count()` to check the total objects in the QuerySet:

```
{% if game.developer.all.count > 1 %} 
   <h1>Developers:</h1>
{% else %} 
   <h1>Developer:</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize

```
<h1>Developer{{ game.developer.count|pluralize }}:</h1>
```